# how to close the CameraCaptureDialog dialog automatically after taking a photo using C#

Tags: windows, mobile, camera, capture

I am doing a work that scans the barcode and gets the information behind it under windows mobile 6.5 and .net compact framework 2.0, using  CameraCaptureDialog class to capture a picture from the phone camera, this is my code:

```
        CameraCaptureDialog cameraCaptureDialog = new CameraCaptureDialog();
        cameraCaptureDialog.Owner = this;
        cameraCaptureDialog.Title = "";
        cameraCaptureDialog.Mode = CameraCaptureMode.Still;
        cameraCaptureDialog.InitialDirectory = dir;
        cameraCaptureDialog.Resolution = new System.Drawing.Size(640, 480);
        cameraCaptureDialog.DefaultFileName = "CodeBar.jpg";

        if (cameraCaptureDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK && cameraCaptureDialog.FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            curFileName = cameraCaptureDialog.FileName;
            cameraCaptureDialog.Dispose();
        }

        //deal with CodeBar.jpg
```

the question is, during my code running, I have to press the capture button on the  cameraCaptureDialog, then press the back button to return to my program to deal with the captured file, this operation needs to press 2 buttons, for user convenience, I want the cameraCaptureDialog to close automatically after the user pressed the capture button, how can this be done? as I know, when ShowDialog() method is called, cameraCaptureDialog won't return until the back button shown on the dialog, so I could do nothing before manually close the cameraCaptureDialog and the ShowDialog() method returned DialogResult.OK